# How to import a csv as a nested dictonary?

Tags: python, csv

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
Benchmark   Workload    Stat1   Stat2
foo         input1      1%      2%
bar         input2      3%      4%
```

Except it's much larger, with more benchmarks,more workloads, and more stats, so it's difficult to hard-code anything that involves knowing the possible values ahead of time.

Is there an easy way that I can import all of this into a python dict so that I can do something like:
stats[benchmark][workload]['stat1']

etc

Comment: There is magical lib called `pandas`

Comment: `CSV` stands for `comma-separated values`. However, I don't see any commas in your data. Can you please post a sample of what the inside of your file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The following code might work for you:

```
import sys
import pathlib

def import_data_from_file(path):
    p = pathlib.Path(path)
    root = dict()
    with open(p , mode = "r") as inf:
        it_inf = iter(inf)
        col_heads = next(it_inf)
        for row in it_inf:
            row = row.strip()
            row = row.split(" ")
            predicate = lambda x: len(x) > 0
            row = list(filter(predicate, row))
            d = root
            benchmark = row[0]
            workload = row[1]
            root.setdefault(benchmark, dict())
            root[benchmark].setdefault(workload, dict())
            root[benchmark][workload] = row[2:]
    return (col_heads, root)

def pprint_data(d, *, sep="", file=sys.stdout):
    _print = lambda *args:\
        print(*args, sep=sep, file=file)
    for benchmark in d.keys():
        _print(benchmark)
        for workload in d[benchmark].keys():
            _print(4 * " ", workload)
            _print(8 * " ", d[benchmark][workload])
    return

col_heads, root = import_data_from_file("dfgdfgdfg.csv")
pprint_data(root)
```

The console output is:

```
foo
    input1
        ['1%', '2%']
bar
    input2
        ['3%', '4%']
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler solution using the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Benchmark', 'Workload', 'Stat1', 'Stat2'])
stats.Benchmark = ['foo', 'bar']
stats.Workload = ['input1', 'input2']
stats.Stat1 = ['1%', '3%']
stats.Stat2 = ['2%', '4%']
```

If you print out your dataframe (`stats`) now, it will look like this:

[image]

The advantage of this over making a nested dictionary, like what you asked for, is that instead of accessing data by writing down all the columns like `stats[benchmark][workload]['stat1']`, you can access elements with only the column name and the index of the element, like this:

```
df.Benchmark[1]
>>> 'bar'

df.Workload[0]
>>> 'input1'

df.Stat1[0]
>>> '1%'

df.Stat2[1]
>>> '4%'
```

You can import a CSV into a pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')
```